# "IS NULL" filter vaadin

Tags: java, spring, vaadin7

Vaadin has filters (and, between, compare, isnull, like, not, or, etc.). Is there a filter in vaadin that I can use to output strings where the value is NULL.
I have a code where a number search is performed using the sql (where) condition, how can I output null values. P.S. a field that does not enter a number by condition outputs all values

```
public String getCondition() {
        if (currentFilter == null || currentFilter.getLines().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        List<String> lines = getSanitizedLines(currentFilter.getLines());
        if (lines.isEmpty())
            return null;

        MultiLineComponentFilter.FilterType filterType = currentFilter.getFilterType();

        Function<String, Container.Filter> map = value -> {
            String likedValue;
            String withoutNumber = "is null";
            switch (filterType) {
                case CONTAINS:
                    likedValue = "%" + value + "%";
                    break;
                case START_WITH:
                    likedValue = value + "%";
                    break;
                case END_WITH:
                    likedValue = "%" + value;
                    break;
                case EQUALS:
                    return new Compare.Equal(colName, value);
                case NOTEXIST:
                    return withoutNumber;

                default:
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unexpected filterType=" + filterType);
            }

            return new Like(colName, likedValue);
        };

        List<Container.Filter> filters = lines.stream().map(map).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return QueryBuilderExt.getPlainJoinedFilterString(filters, "or");
    }
```

Comment: Which Vaadin 7 component or addon are you using?

Comment: @TarekOraby - com.vaadin.data.util.filter